# Implementing an AVL tree using values from a text file

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I am attempting to implement an AVL Tree by using key/value pairs from a text file. For example, (0003,09390,Vegas) would be one such key value pair, with 0003 being the key, and 09390, Vegas being the value. I am confused on how to extract each individual item. I would want 0003, 09390, and Vegas stored as each individual variables in a struct.

Comment: If your text file is well structured data (looks like), it's useful to learn how to read using `scanf`. If its simple enough, `cin/getline` will do the job.

Comment: @VillasV I do not recommend using `scanf`. `std::getline` and `stringstream` is a better solution.

Comment: @erip yes, others SO users yelled me already for recommending `scanf` to new users. I see nothing wrong though, its very good for structured data. I'd recommend against if data is not well structured only.

Comment: `scanf` is not idiomatic C++.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a structure to hold the values:

```
struct Values
{
  std::string value; // such as 09390
  std::string city;  // such as "Vegas"
};
```

Next, overload the extraction operator:

```
struct Values
{
  std::string value; // such as 09390
  std::string city;  // such as "Vegas"
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Values& v);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Values& v)
{
  inp >> v.value;
  // insert code to skip over delimiter.
  inp >> v.city;
  return inp;
}
```

Your input loop could look like this:

```
std::string key;
std::string delimiter;
Values v;
AVL tree;
//...
while (input_file >> key >> delimiter >> v)
{
  tree[key] = v;
}
```

*Note:  the above input expression only works when values are **not** space or tab separated.*

For more information about reading from a file, search StackOverflow for:

- "c++ read file struct"
- "c++ read file csv"

Comment: Sadly, reading `std::string` considers whitespaces as separators. Thus, reading `key` would read the entire thing.

Comment: Yes, I was going to put in a note about that.  This works when the items are not space separated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is probably to use `ignore()` in combination with `std::getline()`:

```
std::string key, code, city;
if (in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '(')
    && std::getline(in, key, ',')
    && std::getline(in, code, ',')
    && std::getline(in, city, ')')) {
    // ...
}
```